# How to modify the size of option field in select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Inside an ionic popup, I have a `select` html property, with `options` inside. Here is my code and the `CSS` applied to it, my question is how can I set the white space on the entire space of the select ?

[image]

[image]

```js
$scope.cat1 = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"];
```

```css
.item-select{
        max-height: 30px;
        border-radius: 10px; 
        // width: 100%;
}

.label-police{
        font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
        font-weight:300;
        background-color:rgba(172,231,242, 0.1);
}

.top-input{
        background-color:rgba(206,240,246, 0.9);
        font-weight:300;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-police">Cat :</label>
<div class="spacer" style="width: 100%; height: 2px;"></div>
<label class="item item-select">
<select class="top-input"><br><option class="top-input" ng-repeat="cat in cat1">{{ cat }}</option></select></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works adding `width: 100%;` into the `.top-input` styles. Also, if you want to adjust it completely, set `.item` div padding to 0.

[Here an approach](http://jsfiddle.net/px55b3c6/)

Comment: Padding didn't work, but you pointed that I was using `<label class="item item-select">` instead of `<div class="item item-select">` around my <select>. I changed it, and it worked, thank you !